# Find an upper bound to the series $\sum_{j=1}^{1000} j^{1/3}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

$\textbf{Question :}$ Prove that the sum $S=\sum_{j=1}^{1000}j^{1/3}$ has an upper bound of atleast $7510$.

$\textbf{My Attempt :}$

As the function $f(x)=x^{1/3}$ is clearly increasing and concave downwards in the region $x  \ge 0$,

$$S>\int_{0}^{1000} x^{1/3} dx = 7500$$
So, $S>7500$

Now I am getting stuck on how to interpolate this integral trick to givc an upper bound instead of a lower bound. One idea I had was that as biggest term of $S$ is $10$ so I should be able to write :

$$S - \sum_{j=1}^{1000}j < \int_{0}^{1000}x^{1/3} dx $$

as subtracting $10$ from each term should make sure it is below $y=x^{1/3}$ but this method gives too large a upper bound to be useful...

Comment: To prove $S$ has an upper bound of at least $7510$, you need to actually show that $7510$ is a *lower* bound for $S$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same method to obtain an upper bound. Note that
$$
 S = \sum_{j=1}^{1000}j^{1/3} < \sum_{j=1}^{1000}\int_{j}^{j+1}x^{1/3} \text{d}x = \int_{1}^{1001}x^{1/3} \text{d}x <7510
$$
since the function $f(x)=x^{1/3}$ is strictly increasing in the region $x>0$.

Comment: can you please tell how did you prove :  $\sum_{j=1}^{1000}j^{1/3} < \sum_{j=1}^{1000}\int_{j}^{j+1}x^{1/3} \text{d}x$

Comment: $ j^{1/3}=\int_{j}^{j+1}j^{1/3} \text{d}x < \int_{j}^{j+1}x^{1/3} \text{d}x$

Answer (score 3):

#### Case 1:

let $f(x) = \sum_1^{1000}x^3$
[image: graph case 1]

From the graph above
$$\int_0^{1000}x^3dx < \sum_1^{1000}x^3$$
$$\implies 7500 < f(x)$$

#### Case 2

let g(x) = $\sum_0^{999}x^3$

now the graph changes to below (note the lower limit is now 0)
[image: graph case 2]

which gives
$$\int_0^{1000}x^3dx > \sum_0^{999}x^3$$
$$\implies 7500 > g(x)$$
$$\implies 7500 > f(x) - (1000)^{1/3}$$
$$\implies 7510 > f(x)$$